# How do I force the update of a DataGrid row when return key is pressed

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of points. I have a handler in the viewmodel that updates the model when a point is edited in the `DataGrid`, and another handler that automatically adds a row to the collection when the `CollectionChanged` event is fired and `args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add`.

My problem occurs when the user adds a row by clicking in the first column of an empty row. The row will be automatically filled, and the cursor will be set to edit the value in the first column. The user will expect to be able to immediately edit the value and hit return to update the `DataGrid`, but it does not work. The handler that fires when a point is edited does not fire, and consequently the data in the model is not updated. To edit this new row the user must first leave, then reenter it. My users wont like this.

To solve the problem I have added a `OnPreviewKeyDown` handler in the view. I have tried both

```
dataGrid.CommitEdit();
```

and

```
dataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

but I still cant get the datagrid to update. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution posted here

http://www.sirentuan.com/3034640/codep1/wpf-datagrid-source-updating-on-cell-changed

I just used `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` on each column, which is much simpler than what I was trying to do.